# Is there any normal solution to edit map in list Aerospike

Tags: javascript, node.js, aerospike

I tried to edit object in list with this variant

```
const { bins: data } = await client.get(key); // { array: [{ variable: 1 }, { variable: 2 }] }
const { array } = await client.operate(key, [Aerospike.maps.put('array', 3).withContext(ctx => ctx.addListIndex(1).addMapKey('variable'))]); // want to edit second object in array, but i get an error 'Operations array invalid'
```

Can i do it normally or only way to do it is just remove object by index and insert new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Aerospike's Map operations to update the nested map value in place!

There are two problems with your `operate` command: The [`maps.put`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike_maps.html#.put__anchor) operation takes 3 parameters: The bin name (`array` in your case), the map key (`variable`) and the new value (`3`). And the context for this operation is just the 2nd list object - no need to add the map key as a context as well.

Here is a full, working example:

```js
// nested-cdt-ops.js
const as = require('aerospike')

as.connect().then(async (client) => {
  const key = new as.Key('test', 'test', 'nested')
  {
    const bins = { array: [{ variable: 1 }, { variable: 2 }] }
    await client.put(key, bins)
    console.log('BEFORE:', bins)
  }

  const operations = [
    as.maps.put('array', 'variable', 3).withContext(
      (ctx) => ctx.addListIndex(1)
    )
  ]
  await client.operate(key, operations)

  {
    const { bins } = await client.get(key)
    console.log('AFTER:', bins)
  }
  client.close()
}).catch((error) => {
  if (error.client) error.client.close()
  console.error(error)
})
```

It outputs:

```
$ node nested-cdt-ops.js
BEFORE: { array: [ { variable: 1 }, { variable: 2 } ] }
AFTER: { array: [ { variable: 1 }, { variable: 3 } ] }
```